# How to declare static field in class

Tags: windows-phone-8, c++-cli

I have a XAML + DirectX app and I want to add static field to my "interop" class:

```
[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class Direct3DInterop sealed : public Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::IDrawingSurfaceManipulationHandler
{
public:
    static int VALUE = 0;
    ...
};
```

It does not compile saying "*only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class*".

If I change it to `const static int VALUE = 0;` then it still does not compile with error "*a non-value type cannot have any public data members*"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *declare* within the class body, and define/assign outside the class body. `static int VALUE;` ... `int Direct3DInterop::VALUE = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRT public classes have a number of limitations to ensure they are consumable by multiple languages including C++, JavaScript, and C#. This is why you are getting error C3984. You can't have public fields and instead must use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755807.aspx). You'd make it a read-only property:

```
property int VALUE
{
    int get() { return 0; }
}
```

It is important to remember that properties are function calls and can't usually be optimized away, so you should consider that when designing the interfaces.

If you intend to have this class only consumable by C++, consider not using a WinRT class and instead use a simple C++ class which you managed the lifetime using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. In that case, you can of course use the public field approach as always.

The original problem you got is a general C++ language restriction not specific to WinRT. Error  [C2864](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxkb76w(v=vs.110).aspx) (you are using VS 2012 from the text you posted) is a little more general with C++11 in [VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxkb76w.aspx).

Comment: Note that if you just want it to be "public" inside C++ and not projected via WinRT, you can use "internal" visibility instead.